# How can we truncate table using the Grails domain or GORM?

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to truncate my table named as `scraper_proxies`. I can truncate this table using the native SQL like below:

```
int truncateResult = session.createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE scraper_proxies").executeUpdate()
```

**Requirement**

But i want to truncate this table using the Grails domain named as `ScraperProxies` which is mapped with `scraper_proxies` table.

Is anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Delete all `ScraperProxies` records in the database using the **Grails domain**:

```
Integer result = ScraperProxies.executeUpdate("delete ScraperProxies")
```

It will return the integer value. If it deletes the 5 rows than return value will be 5.